# Rolling sum on an unbalanced time series

Tags: r, time-series, plyr

I have a series of annual incident counts per category, with no rows for years in which the category did not see an incident. I would like to add a column that shows, for each year, how many incidents occurred in the previous three years.

One way to handle this is to add empty rows for all years with zero incidents, then use `rollapply()` with a left-aligned four year window, but that would expand my data set more than I want to. Surely there's a way to use `ddply()` and `transform` for this?

The following two lines of code build a dummy data set, then execute a simple `plyr` sum by category:

```
dat <- data.frame(
   category=c(rep('A',6), rep('B',6), rep('C',6)), 
   year=rep(c(2000,2001,2004,2005,2009, 2010),3), 
   incidents=rpois(18, 3)
   )

ddply(dat, .(category) , transform, i_per_c=sum(incidents) )
```

That works, but it only shows a per-category total.

I want a total that's year-dependent.

So I try to expand the `ddply()` call with the `function()` syntax, like so:

```
ddply(dat, .(category) , transform, 
      function(x) i_per_c=sum(ifelse(x$year >= year - 4 & x$year < year,  x$incidents, 0) )
      )
```

This just returns the original data frame, unmodified.

I must be missing something in the `plyr` syntax, but I don't know what it is.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sorta ugly, but it works. Nested ply calls:

```
ddply(dat, .(category), 
    function(datc) adply(datc, 1, 
         function(x) data.frame(run_incidents =
                                sum(subset(datc, year>(x$year-2) & year<=x$year)$incidents))))
```

There might be a slightly cleaner way to do it, and there are definitely ways that execute much faster.

Comment: Harlan, thanks. That looks like it might work, but where does `qq` get assigned?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Had a temporary variable in there from testing. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. This remains the best solution I've come up with.

Comment: The idea here is nice, but it gives the wrong answer. Instead of representing the number of incidents in the previous three years, the new column contains the number of incidents in the current year plus the incidents in the previous two years. (To most clearly see this, assign the output to `d`, and then sort with `d[order(d$category, d$year),]`.)

Comment: Josh- You're right. Since I had to edit Harlan's answer to fit my real data anyway, it was no big deal to fix the arithmetic along the way. The double `transform()` is what I was looking for.