# Performing (unbalanced) time series validation (with data.table?)

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947952/rolling-sum-on-an-unbalanced-time-series), I attempted to validate my dataset utilizing nested ddply statements. I have performance issues, however, with the code taking nearly an hour to run on each run (300,000 firm-years.

This is not necessarily a problem (as I don't need to rerun that often), but I'd like to know how I could improve its performance or do it differently to learn from it.

The problem I'm having here, is that I need to validate an (unbalanced) time series dataset, according to a few rules.

An example dataset is as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame (
  FirmID = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10),"c",rep("d",10)),
  Year   = c(rep(c(2000:2004,2006:2010),2),2000,c(2000:2004,2006:2010)),
  Random1 = rep("test",31),
  Random2 = rep("test2",31),
  Assets = rpois(31,3),
  Sales  = rpois(31,3)
)

dat$Assets[c(1,11)] <- NA
dat$Sales[c(2,11)]  <- NA
dat$Assets[21] <- NA
    dat$Sales[21] <- NA
```

The first test I need is whether the data is complete for each individual row. This snippet tests whether any of the required columns is NA, and returns OK if all values are valid:

```
require(plyr)
RequiredVariables <- c("Assets", "Sales")
ValidateT0 <- ddply(dat, .(FirmID,Year),
      function(dat) AnyNA = ifelse(sum(is.na(dat[,names(dat) %in% RequiredVariables]))==0,"OK",NA))
dat <- merge(dat,ValidateT0)
dat <- rename(dat, c("V1"="ValidRow")) # Somehow the variable name was wrong?
dat
```

This returns the following dataset.

```
   FirmID Year Assets Sales ValidRow
1       a 2000     NA     2     <NA>
2       a 2001      1    NA     <NA>
3       a 2002      5     3       OK
4       a 2003      5     3       OK
5       a 2004      1     6       OK
6       a 2006      3     4       OK
7       a 2007      3     0       OK
8       a 2008      4     3       OK
9       a 2009      5     3       OK
10      a 2010      3     4       OK
11      b 2000     NA    NA     <NA>
12      b 2001      4     3       OK
13      b 2002      5     1       OK
14      b 2003      1     4       OK
15      b 2004      4     2       OK
16      b 2006      6     2       OK
17      b 2007      3     3       OK
18      b 2008      2     4       OK
19      b 2009      7     6       OK
20      b 2010      3     5       OK
21      c 2000     NA    NA     <NA>
22      d 2000      0     2       OK
23      d 2001      4     1       OK
24      d 2002      3     4       OK
25      d 2003      4     0       OK
26      d 2004      3     6       OK
27      d 2006      6     4       OK
28      d 2007      7     0       OK
29      d 2008      6     2       OK
30      d 2009      4     6       OK
31      d 2010      0     1       OK
```

Then, for each year, I specify three (relative) periods for which I need data for separate analyses (I'm doing a study on acquisitions, I need data on the acquirer for T-2, T-1 & T+1, T+2, etc.):

```
AcqPeriod <- c(-2, -1, 1, 2)
TargetPeriod <- c(-3, -2, -1)
LogitPeriod <- c(-2, -1)
```

Now I want to validate, for each row, whether it is useable in one of my analyses, this is where the nested ddply comes in:

```
ValidatePeriods <- ddply(dat, .(FirmID), 
   function(datc) adply(datc, 1, 
    function(x) data.frame(
      AsAcquirerOK =
         sum(!is.na(subset(datc, Year %in%(x$Year+AcqPeriod))$ValidRow))==length(AcqPeriod),
      AsTargetOK =
         sum(!is.na(subset(datc, Year %in% (x$Year+TargetPeriod))$ValidRow))==length(TargetPeriod),
      AsLogitOK =
         sum(!is.na(subset(datc, Year %in% (x$Year+LogitPeriod))$ValidRow))==length(LogitPeriod)

                                       )
                  )
)
ValidatePeriods
```

This code, while being hard to read, works in an intuitive way as I'm able to specify exactly what I need within a few lines of code. It tests for each firm-year whether all rows in the specified periods exists (==length(period) part) and contain valid values via !is.na on the previously generated 'ValidRow' column.

It returns exactly what I require:

```
       FirmID Year Assets Sales ValidRow AsAcquirerOK AsTargetOK AsLogitOK
1       a 2000     NA     6     <NA>        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
2       a 2001      1    NA     <NA>        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
3       a 2002      3     3       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
4       a 2003      4     0       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
5       a 2004      5     3       OK        FALSE      FALSE      TRUE
6       a 2006      1     6       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
7       a 2007      3     3       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
8       a 2008      1     2       OK         TRUE      FALSE      TRUE
9       a 2009      1     0       OK        FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
10      a 2010      2     0       OK        FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
11      b 2000     NA    NA     <NA>        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
12      b 2001      2     0       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
13      b 2002      5     2       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
14      b 2003      4     2       OK        FALSE      FALSE      TRUE
15      b 2004      1     4       OK        FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
16      b 2006      4     3       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
17      b 2007      3     2       OK        FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
18      b 2008      4     1       OK         TRUE      FALSE      TRUE
19      b 2009      2     2       OK        FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
20      b 2010      3     3       OK        FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
```

However, as previously stated, this function takes ~ 52 minutes on a dataset comprised of 300,000 firmyears.

I tried to incorporate data.tables's speed, but I'm relatively unsure regarding how I should do it. I defined the following function in order to quickly add T-1... (_Tm1) or T+1.. (_Tp1) columns to my table. :

```
AddTimeSeriesCols <- function(data=dt, Periods=c(-1), keys=c("FirmID","Year")){
  require(data.table)
  require(stringr)
  dt <- data.table(data)
  setkeyv(dt, cols=keys)

  dtFinal <- copy(dt)   # Duplicate dt to add columns to
  for (i in Periods){
    StartColumn <- length(names(dt))+1  # First Column to Rename

    Tm <- data.table(transform(dt, Year=Year-i)) # Create lagged dataset
    setkey(Tm, FirmID,Year)                      # 

    dtCurrent<-merge(dt, Tm, by = c("FirmID","Year"), all.x = TRUE) # Join with T-/+x

    OldNames <- names(dtCurrent)[StartColumn:length(names(dtCurrent))] # Define old names to change
    ifelse(i < 0, middle <- "m",ifelse(i>0,middle <- "p",middle <-"")) # Define middle part in Suffix
    Suffix <- paste("_","T",middle,abs(i), sep="") # Define Suffix, Tm1 for T(-1), Tp1 for T(+1)

    NewNames <- str_c(str_sub(OldNames,1,-3),Suffix)  # Generate new names
    setnames(dtCurrent,OldNames, NewNames)            # Rename data table

    KeepKey <- 1:(length(names(dt))-length(NewNames)) # I only want the lagged values
    KeepNew <- StartColumn:length(names(dtCurrent))   # & keys of the original dt when merging

    dtCurrent <- dtCurrent[,j=c(KeepKey,KeepNew), with=FALSE] # Data Table with original FirmYear + lagged values
    dtFinal <- merge(dtFinal,dtCurrent, by = c("FirmID","Year")) # Append to a separate copy in order to reuse original dataframe.
  }
  return(dtFinal)
}
```

It returns a datatable with the added (lagged) columns and runs in nearly 2 seconds on the entire (300k rows) dataset. It takes care of joining to the relevant lagged years and names the variables in a consistent way (_Tm1 for T-1, _Tp1 for T+1 etc.):

```
>AddTimeSeriesCols(data=dat,c(-3, -2, -1))
    FirmID Year Assets Sales RowOK Assets_Tm3 Sales_Tm3 RowOK_Tm3 Assets_Tm2 Sales_Tm2 RowOK_Tm2 Assets_Tm1 Sales_Tm1 RowOK_Tm1
 1:      a 2000     NA     1    NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
 2:      a 2001      3    NA    NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA         NA         1        NA
 3:      a 2002      4     3    OK         NA        NA        NA         NA         1        NA          3        NA        NA
 4:      a 2003      1     1    OK         NA         1        NA          3        NA        NA          4         3        OK
 5:      a 2004      2     0    OK          3        NA        NA          4         3        OK          1         1        OK
 6:      a 2006      5     5    OK          1         1        OK          2         0        OK         NA        NA        NA
 7:      a 2007      2     4    OK          2         0        OK         NA        NA        NA          5         5        OK
 8:      a 2008      4     2    OK         NA        NA        NA          5         5        OK          2         4        OK
 9:      a 2009      2     1    OK          5         5        OK          2         4        OK          4         2        OK
10:      a 2010      5     2    OK          2         4        OK          4         2        OK          2         1        OK
11:      b 2000     NA    NA    NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
12:      b 2001      3     6    OK         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
13:      b 2002      1     3    OK         NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA          3         6        OK
14:      b 2003      4     5    OK         NA        NA        NA          3         6        OK          1         3        OK
15:      b 2004      0     3    OK          3         6        OK          1         3        OK          4         5        OK
16:      b 2006      3     3    OK          4         5        OK          0         3        OK         NA        NA        NA
17:      b 2007      2     5    OK          0         3        OK         NA        NA        NA          3         3        OK
18:      b 2008      4     3    OK         NA        NA        NA          3         3        OK          2         5        OK
19:      b 2009      3     4    OK          3         3        OK          2         5        OK          4         3        OK
20:      b 2010      5     1    OK          2         5        OK          4         3        OK          3         4        OK
```

This would technically allow me to do a similar validations much faster, but would require a much different syntax for validation (I'd have to name specific columns rather than putting in a vector of c(-3, -2, -1) etc.)

My questions here:

1. In the ValidateT0 snippet: why is my variable not properly named, causing me to add a rename row?
2. How would I improve the speed of the ddply option, or should I step away from these nested ddply functions?
3. How would I write a snippet that tests my validation rules, utilizing an imput in the format of c(-3, -2, -1)? Or how would I refer to these columns effectively in the newly created data table with lagged values (as created by my function)?

Thank you for any help, Stackoverflow has been amazingly helpful in teaching me how to do these kind of analyses without any prior programming knowledge.

## Edit: added a more realistic dataset.

Comment: do you ever have the same year twice for the same `FirmId`?

Comment: I do not, FirmYear is unique.

Comment: Ok, what about your "periods" - are they always spaced by one year as in the example above or can you have a period that is e.g. `c(-5, -3, -1)`?

Comment: I inserted all missing years between the minimum year and max year artifically (as NA), I'd prefer to learn how to do this without doing so in order to prevent any insertions on the original dataset though. They do not all have the same minimum / maximum year. Some firms only have 1985, some firms have 1985-2012, some firms have 1986-1990. And sorry, you were referring to something else: the perods c(-3,-2,-1) most likely will be yearly and sequential. Though, again, I'd like to be able to do this without limiting myself to one-year spaced periods.

Comment: ok, if you do limit yourself to 1-year spaced periods, you can speed this up significantly by, e.g. for your `TargetPeriod`, counting how many consecutive years up to this year and simply comparing that number with 3 - `cumsum` and `diff` will help you there (and you can find a ton of questions along those lines on SO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer taking advantage of `data.table` and the base function `embed`:

#### Data:

```
dat <- data.frame (
         FirmID = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),
         Year   = rep(c(2000:2004,2006:2010),2),
         Assets = rpois(20,3),
         Sales  = rpois(20,3)
       )

dat$Assets[c(1,11)] <- NA
dat$Sales[c(2,11)]  <- NA

RequiredVariables <- c("Assets", "Sales")
```

#### Step 1:

To construct `ValidRow`, we just construct the expresssion `is.na(Assets) | is.na(Sales)` as follows:

```
tmp <- lapply(RequiredVariables, 
          function(x) as.call(lapply(c("is.na", x), as.name)))
gg <- function(x, y, op=as.name("|")) as.call(list(op,x,y))
expr = tmp[[1L]]
for (i in 2:length(expr)) 
    expr = gg(expr, tmp[[i]])

> expr
# is.na(Assets) | is.na(Sales)
> class(expr)
# [1] "call"
```

We can now use this expression in `i` in `data.table` and create the new column `ValidRow` by reference as follows:

```
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[!eval(expr), ValidRow := "OK"]
```

The `i` expression is evaluated, then negateed (`!`) and all these entries get the value `OK`. The other entries, by default will be `NA`.

#### Step 2:

Now, we''ll use `embed` to generate all the lead/lag'd years (by default it gives a matrix) and then use `apply` to loop through. You may've to spend some time in understanding this part.

```
ff <- function(x, p, k) {
    min_k = if (min(k) > 0L) 0L else min(k)
    max_k = if (max(k) < 0L) 0L else max(k)

    len = length(k)
    full_range = min_k:max_k
    idx = which(!full_range %in% k)
    full_years = (min(x)+min_k):(max(x)+max_k)
    mat = embed(full_years, length(full_range))
    idx = ncol(mat) - idx + 1L
    if (length(idx)) mat = mat[mat[, idx] %in% x, , drop=FALSE][, -(idx), drop=FALSE]
    apply(mat, 1, function(mm) sum(!is.na(p[x %in% mm])) == len)
}
```

We make sure that the data is sorted by "FirmID" and then by "Year" with `setkey`. Then, we call `ff()` three times for each of your lead/lag vectors.

```
setkey(DT, FirmID, Year)
DT[, `:=`(bla1 = ff(Year, ValidRow, AcqPeriod), 
          bla2 = ff(Year, ValidRow, TargetPeriod),
          bla3 = ff(Year, ValidRow, LogitPeriod))
, by=FirmID]
})
```

This gives:

```
#     FirmID Year Assets Sales ValidRow  bla1  bla2  bla3
#  1:      a 2000     NA     3       NA FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  2:      a 2001      0    NA       NA FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  3:      a 2002      4     1       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  4:      a 2003      1     7       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  5:      a 2004      2     2       OK FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  6:      a 2006      3     3       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  7:      a 2007      3     5       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  8:      a 2008      1     4       OK  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#  9:      a 2009      4     6       OK FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 10:      a 2010      2     1       OK FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 11:      b 2000     NA    NA       NA FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 12:      b 2001      2     3       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 13:      b 2002      4     5       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 14:      b 2003      2     2       OK FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 15:      b 2004      4     6       OK FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 16:      b 2006      2     3       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 17:      b 2007      3     8       OK FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 18:      b 2008      2     3       OK  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 19:      b 2009      1     4       OK FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 20:      b 2010      2     1       OK FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This seems about ~16x faster than your current solution. I'm guessing on your big data, you should've significant speedup. Let me know how long this takes..

I couldn't find a way to avoid the `apply` loop. It'd be nice to know how long this one takes on your actual dataset.

HTH.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! I'm currently in the process of understanding the ff function. I tried it on my dataset & it returns an error: "Error in mat[mat[, idx] %in% x, ][, -(idx)]: incorrect number of dimensions"
Furthermore, as I simplified the example in order to only have two columns to check, I changed the expression builder to accept more than two input variables: "for (i in length(RequiredVariables):length(expr))" 

This did not cause the initial error, however. I see the last code ran  and added columns until a FirmYear row for which I only have one year of data?  I'll keep trying. Thanks again

Comment: If you can produce a small dataset (like the one before) where you get this error, I might try and see where the problem is.

Comment: I added a new dataset to the original question: notice that firm C has only one year and has two NA values. I could remove such values beforehand? The 'Random' variables would replicate my redundant extra columns, I am not sure whether it makes a difference for your code, I am still trying to make it work.

Comment: Was an issue with `drop` - subsetting a 1 row matrix returns a vector without `drop=FALSE`. Try it again now.

Comment: Getting a 23 second run on 300,000 firm years now :) Thanks a lot! Now off to understanding what you did. Second & third run at 20-some seconds.

Comment: WHAT!!?!? 135x speedup? My goodness! That's much more than I expected. It's very easy to see what I've done. Use `debugonce(ff)` and do: `DT[, print(bla1 = ff(Year, ValidRow, AcqPeriod), by=FirmID]` and keep hitting enter and check the values in each step. good luck!